# how do I exclude specific paths when using MarkLogic search:search

Tags: marklogic

I have xml docs in a MarkLogic database with a `description` element at several paths. For example `.../program/description` and `.../certification/description`. I want to exclude just the `.../certification/description` for a particular search.

Since I don't want to exclude `.../certification/description` from all searches, I don't want to use the database `word-query` config to do this.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting when you cannot use the built-in include and exclude options.

A few options I can think of:

- Set a field for each location of the description (program-description, certification-description), etc.

  - Then you can query them with cts:field-[value |word]-query - both of which take a sequence for he field name. Therefore you are able to turn on and off which ones are included.
- Affect the same with path range indexes

Both of the above will add some storage overhead (and in the case of the fields, a slight cost at time of index). But It does allow you to elegantly switch which locations are included.

Another option would be to scope your query and include only the target descriptions by using a [`cts:element-query`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-query) as container. In this case, target just the program element and its children.

Comment: Thanks David. We want our word searches to include all text in the doc except certification/description.  We ended up moving the certification/description data into an attribute (certification/@description which should give the effect we want.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up moving the `certification/description` data into an attribute (`certification/@description`) which should give us the behavior we want.